# Using .NET Introspection / FxCop Rules functionality in Unit Tests

Tags: .net, unit-testing, fxcop, introspection

is it possible to use the .NET Introspection functionality in unit tests?
In our software I#d like to prohibit usage of some operations (comparison of enum values since there as a special method for that purpose). I remember that FxCop (Static Code Analysis) ofers access to the code model by means of Introspection. With it, you can inspect whether some function is used or not. I' d like to write a unit test making the same check but I'm not sure whether Introspection or something similar is offered to the unit test.
Or maybe you have another idea how I could do it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there some particular reason that you want to do this via unit testing instead of simply creating a custom FxCop rule?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that FxCop internals cannot be used [externally](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/af3e1cd9-e482-471a-b757-2d14c26d7c58)  (except in FxCop itself or in Visual Studio).

If you want to validate your architecture, you can try PostSharp feature [Architecture validation](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Architectural-Validation.aspx) or a FxCop Mono alternative [Gendarme](http://www.mono-project.com/Gendarme).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about FxCop, but you can use .NET Reflection (is that what you mean by introspection?) to enforce certain code behaviors.

For example, I have used Reflection in some tests to make sure that certain "internal" types are not exposed via our public service API.  We just looped over our public API and verified that no exposed types (method arguments, properties, etc...) were in the "internal" type list.  This was very handy where we were wrapping 3rd-party components, but we wanted to ensure that none of the types in their library were exposed via our API.

If you are not familiar with .NET reflection, it gives you an API which lets you query types for information like class methods, method arguments, class properties, etc... You can start with the overview here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I have enum UserRole { ... } and I'd like to make sure the role comparison is not by means of is-equal operation but by means of special method. Reflection doesn't give me the ability to check the whole source code. Therefore I ask about Introspection ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The tool NDepend can help you do that thanks to [NDepend.API](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html). *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

NDepend.API proposes the namespace [NDepend.CodeModel](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel_namespace.html) that contains all types and member needed to introspect a .NET code base.

With NDepend.API you can write unit tests to check a wide-range of issues, like [unused methods](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Methods.html) for example. *NDepend.CodeModel* has been designed to be LINQ-syntax friendly, and [200 of LINQ default code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed by default (written with what we call [CQLinq](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL)).